# Как прервать выполнение функции до команды от пользователя?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qt5, c++17

Есть исходники библиотеки, где необходимо остановить выполнение одной из функций до отдельного согласия пользователя. Примерно так я думал сделать:

```
void someFunc(bool withConfirm) {
    /*some code*/
    if (withConfirm) {
        QMessageBox::information(nullptr, "someFunc остановлен", "Нажми ОК, что бы продолжить");
    }
    /*some code*/
}
```

Вот только работа с библиотекой происходит не в главном потоке, поэтому нельзя напрямую использовать `QMessageBox`. Как можно проинформировать главный поток или объект `MainWindow`, что бы уведомить пользователя, а потом продолжить работу?

Comment: сделайте слот в MainWindow с вызовом QMessageBox и вызывайте этот слот из потока с помощью `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` с аргументом `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`

Comment: не понятно как передать указатель на `MainWindow` функции `invokeMethod`

Comment: @PavelGridin проблема в том, что библиотека собирается отдельно и в основной проект подключается только dll. Поэтому не могу собрать библиотеку без основного проекта. А это плохо.

Comment: Библиотека Ваша работает только в рамках проекта? Сделайте интерфейс, который позволит использовать систему сигнал-слотов. И используйте все прелести Qt. Почитайте про систему plugins в Qt

Comment: @RomanOzhegov, `connect`-ы создают таблицы по которым в конце концов вызываются слоты с помощью `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`. И иногда проще вызвать слот впрямую, чем городить connect/emit

Comment: @KtoTo, можно использовать любой `QObject` из главного потока, надо только понимать, что `invokeMethod` попадёт в очередь и будет оттуда взят на выполнение во время обработки функцией `eventLoop`

Comment: @KtoTo, да ещё имейте ввиду, что указатель на объект можно найти по его имени - `QObject::findChild`